# How to calculate Exponential Moving average for a Stock

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stock, smoothing

I have searched a lot and every authour of Website gave a formula for EMA Calculation as shown below

```
EMA = EMAp + {K * (Price - EMAp)}

EMA = exponential moving average
EMAp = the previous period exponential moving average
K = smoothing constant
Price = current price
```

But nobody has mentioned how to get the **previous period exponential moving average**

Could you please tell me how to get the previous day EMA ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exponential smoothing is a [recursive formula for time-series analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing). As a basis case, you start with the actual data for the first time series data point. So, in your case you would use the actual stock price for the first day and then start using your formula for the second day.

Answer (score 3):

While calculating EMA at first we lack the 1st point of EMA as you have mentioned, So we take value of SMA (Simple Moving Average) of the same period which we r using for EMA

```
SMA Point 1 = (45 + 46 + 43 + 44 + 42 + 41 + 40 + 39 + 41 + 40) ÷ 10 = 42.1
SMA Point 2 = (46 + 43 + 44 + 42 + 41 + 40 + 39 + 41 + 40 + 38) ÷ 10 = 41.4
SMA Point 3 = (43 + 44 + 42 + 41 + 40 + 39 + 41 + 40 + 38 + 36) ÷ 10 = 40.4
```

For period of 10 days,  k = 2 ÷ (Period + 1)

```
k = 2 ÷ (10 + 1) = 2 ÷ 11 = 0.1818
```

EMA = ((Current price - Previous EMA) × k) + Previous EMA

```
EMA Point 1 = ((38 - 42.1) × 0.1818) + 42.1 = 41.35 (have used SMA Point 1 as Previous EMA)
EMA Point 2 = ((36 - 41.35) × 0.1818) + 41.35 = 40.38 
& so on....
```

Hope this solves ur problem, feel free to ask if u have any doubt.